# could not add sharepoint.client.runtime c# visual studio mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, sharepoint-online

Hi I tried to add a sharepoint.client.runtime nuget package but It could not add sharepoint.client.runtime c# visual studio, then i tried to add sharepoint.client.runtime.dll to reference.When i try to build my project Im getting error like this Error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Configuration`, referenced by `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Configuration`, or remove the reference to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime`. (XA2002) Please Give a Solution to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well - have you tried doing what was suggested in the error? or what have you otherwise tried?

Comment: i added a sharepoint.client.runtime.dll to Reference.Then I build my project  getting error like this "Error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: System.Configuration, referenced by Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for System.Configuration, or remove the reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime. (XA2002) " https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM4PO.png

Comment: Yes - i'm seeing the same issue as you. Read the actual error message closer - what does it say you should do to resolve the issue? And have you tried applying that suggestion and does that work or not?

Comment: i tried applying all. If i remove sharepoint.client.runrime.dll,error will resolve. but i should add sharepoint.client.runrime nuget package to my project. how can i add this?

Comment: The error explicitly saids 'Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for System.Configuration' not 'sharepoint.client.runrime'. To install nuget packages, see the nuget.org site, for example: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client/ Are you following a tutorial or something? it may be that you need different packages/dlls because you're using xamarin.

Comment: I try to add Nuget Package But i couldn't add, Showing like this, I don't know Why. Please Help me to solve this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCMbR.png

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not familiar with either sharepoint or xamarin, the only thing i can tell you now that its likely that you need xamarin-specfic dlls for sharepoint. System.Configuration seems like a system dll, and that is usually in the .net framework. It seems that Xamarin uses the mono framework, not .net. This means you need specific libraries for xamarin. Perhaps google  'use sharepoint in xamarin app'? Or wait a bit for someone else to come along who has more experience with either technologies.